# How can I send email attachments from Wordpress pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I have a wordpress page that I want to contain a simple upload form that I want to have the files uploaded to it sent to a specific email address every time.

I'm kind of a beginner at this, so could anybody please tell me how this could be done? I am interested specifically in what should I write in the page content and where should I write the relevant code if it is necessary. Setting a file size limit is a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a popular plugin like [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/). It allows you to set file upload size limit as well.

Using a plugin is so much easier then coding it yourself.

Comment: I did think about this exact plugin but wherever I have seen it it didn't have any options to send email attachments. I just did not think that it can do this.